# подвечивание названия страницы при переходе

Tags: php

допустим у меня есть несколько файлов: `main.php`, `about.php` и `header.php`, в `header` у меня прописана шапка для всего сайта и подключена через `<? php require "header.php" ?>` на каждую страницу, в самой шапке идет по классике название каждой страницы, в данном случае "Главная" и "О нас". Как можно реализовать функцию, чтобы не меняя `header.php`, при переходе по страницам, подсвечивалось цветом текста название каждой из страниц?

Подключить `js` на каждую страницу отдельно и через получение определённых элементов с нужным классом менять стиль, это конечно вариант, но слишком много выйдет `js` файлов

Comment: Наверное имеется ввиду некое меню/навигация?

Comment: @Simon, именно оно, обычная шапка, которая на всех сайтах есть

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не понял что Вы там хотели сделать с подключением кучи JS файлов. Ну допустим, можете создать массив с страницами и их заголовками:

```
<?php
$pages = [
    'index.php'   => 'Главная',
    'about.php'   => 'О нас',
    'contact.php' => 'Контакты'
];

$current = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
?>
<div id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($pages as $page => $title) : ?>
            <li <?php if($page === $current) : ?>class="active"<?php endif; ?>>
                <a href="<?php echo $page; ?>">
                    <?php echo $title; ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Ну и для `active` пропишите необходимые Вам стили.

Давайте теперь проясним.

- Мы создаем массив с страницами, и их заголовками. Ключем будет
  название php файла на который совершается переход, а значением её
  заголовок.
- Далее мы получаетм текущую страницу из переменной `$_SERVER` которая является массивом и обратимся к ключу `REQUEST_URI`. `REQUEST_URI` -- URI, который был предоставлен для доступа к этой странице. Например, '/about.php'. И получим последний компонент имени из указанного пути при помощи функции [basename()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.basename.php).
- При помощи перебора массива выведем необходимые нам данные в меню, такие как заголовок страницы и `href` по которому и будем переходить.
- Для того чтобы когда необходимо выводить класс `active` мы проверим равенство `$page === $current`.

Comment: можете немного пояснить как что работает? я только начал php изучать и сложновато даётся

Comment: @Joker обновил ответ

Comment: т.е. мы с помощью цикла заполняем список, при этом через условие проверяем каждый пункт по ссылкам, и если один из них совпадает с действующей ссылкой, мы выдаём ему определённый класс?

Comment: @Joker все верно

Comment: Спасибо за хороший ответ и осмысленный код. Только выводить данные лучше специальным тегом `<?=`. Вставки РНР в хтмл выглядят довольно коряво, и если есть возможность немного их оптимизировать, то лучше воспользоваться такой возможностью.